# {"Incorrect syntax near ','."}

Tags: c#, sql

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to open a form in my C# App and I don't know what might be the problem. The error is in this line of code `DataTable dt = new DataTable(); dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());`

Error:

> {"Incorrect syntax near ','."}

```
 public void popTraseu()
    {
        string cs = "Data Source=CODRINMA\\CODRINMA;Initial Catalog=TrafficManager;Integrated Security=True";
        string select = "ats.NrOrdine, a.IDAutogara, a.Denumire as Autogara, o.Oras as Oras, o.Judet FROM Curse c INNER JOIN Trasee t on c.IDTraseu=t.IDTraseu INNER JOIN AutogariTrasee ats on t.IDTraseu=ats.IDTraseu INNER JOIN Autogari a on ats.IDAutogara=a.IDAutogara INNER JOIN Orase o on a.IDOras=o.IDOras where IDCursa=@IDCursa ORDER BY ats.NrOrdine";

        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection (cs))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(select, con);
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("IDCursa", int.Parse(grdCurse.CurrentRow.Cells[0].FormattedValue.ToString()));
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                con.Close();
                grdDetalii.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
       catch (Exception er) { MessageBox.Show(er.Message); }
```

Comment: The `SELECT` keyword is missing from the beginning of your statement.

Comment: BTW, [`select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384087.aspx) is a *contextual keyword* in C# - you probably should choose a different name for this variable because even though your C# code is valid as is, it can be confusing.

Comment: Missing `Select` keyword

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to put `select` at the beginning of your query.

```
string select = "select ats.NrOrdine, a.IDAutogara, a.Denumire as Autogara, o.Oras as Oras, o.Judet FROM Curse c INNER JOIN Trasee t on c.IDTraseu=t.IDTraseu INNER JOIN AutogariTrasee ats on t.IDTraseu=ats.IDTraseu INNER JOIN Autogari a on ats.IDAutogara=a.IDAutogara INNER JOIN Orase o on a.IDOras=o.IDOras where IDCursa=@IDCursa ORDER BY ats.NrOrdine";
```

Answer (score 2):

Your select does not start with a SELECT. Hence the syntax of your SQL statement is invalid.

Also note this line:

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

is completely superfluous. There are no parameters in a new instance.